# The Neumann Problem on a Half-space when dimension is $2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, laplacian

Take $\Omega:=\{x=(x_1,x_2):\,-\infty<x_1<\infty,\,x_2>0\}$, i.e., the half-space, and I am interested in the Neumann problem 
\begin{cases}
\Delta u=0&x\in \Omega\\
\partial_2u(x_1,0)=f(x_1),&-\infty<x_1<\infty
\end{cases}
where $f$ is continuous.

I am able to work out the Green's function for this problem and I have
$$ u(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log |(y_1-x_1)^2+x_2^2|\cdot f(y_1)dy_1 $$

Now I am trying to prove that $u$ is bounded if and only if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1)dx_1=0$.

I can not do both directions...

The problem is for unbounded domain, we can not apply Gauss-Green's formula directly, o.w. the only if part would be easy. But I highly suspect in this case I do can use Gauss-Green's formula, or the divergence formula... But I can not prove it. Also for if part, I don't really have an idea... Any help is really welcome!

Comment: I think that $f$ should have compact support too.

Comment: @Tomás maybe you're right. Well let's assume it. Then, will it work? Or maybe we could assume $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ just bounded the integral can diverge (e.g. for $f\equiv 1$). If $f$ has compact support then passing to the polar coordinates, $x_1=r\cos\varphi$ etc. and expanding the kernel on the powers of $r=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}$ we have
$$
\log |(y_1-x_1)^2+x_2^2|=2 \log r-\frac{2 y_1 \cos \varphi
   }{r}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right),\quad r\to\infty,
$$
and
$$
u(x)=2 \log r\int_{\mathbb R}f(y_1)\,dy_1+O(r^{-1}).
$$

**Update**

May be the requirement of compact support can be replaced by a suitable vanishing of $f$, say as $|x_1|^{-2}$. Perhaps to get a better understanding of necessary and suffitient conditions on $f$ one can map conformly the half-plane on the unit circle. The integral of $f$ will turn into in an integral with some weight on the unit circumference.